# Taking Sample in SQL Query

Tags: sql, teradata, sample, random

I'm working on a problem which is something like this :

I have a table with many columns but major are `DepartmentId` and `EmployeeIds`

```
Employee Ids    Department Ids
------------------------------
A                   1
B                   1
C                   1
D                   1
AA                  2
BB                  2
CC                  2
A1                  3
B1                  3
C1                  3
D1                  3
```

I want to write a SQL query such that I take out 2 sample `EmployeeIds` for each `DepartmentID`.

like

```
Employee Id  Dept Ids
B              1
C              1
AA             2
CC             2
D1             3
A1             3
```

Currently I am writing the query,

```
select
   EmployeeId, DeptIds, count(*)
from 
   table_name
group by 1,2
sample 2
```

but it gives me total two rows.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of departments i know and small you could do a stratified sampling:

```
select *
from table_name
sample
   when DeptIds = 1 then 2
   when DeptIds = 2 then 2
   when DeptIds = 3 then 2
end
```

Otherwise a combination of RANDOM and ROW_NUMBER:

```
select *
from
 (
   sel EmployeeId, DeptIds, random(1,10000000) as rand
   from table_name
 ) as dt
qualify
   row_number()
   over (partition by DeptIds
         order by rand) <= 2
```

Comment: i got error on the query that uses Random and Row number:

Comment: Syntax error, expected smth like a name or a unicode delimated identifier or an 'UDFCaLLName' Keyword Between ')' and the 'Qualify' keyword

Comment: Ops, I forgot the alias for the Derived Table, fixed it,